# What is the upper bound of the inner for loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I understand that the upper bound (i.e. for (int i = 0; **i < n**; i++) for a non-nested/single for loop is the worst case time complexity. Basically, **n** is the maximum number of times the for loop will iterate. With this piece of information in mind, here is pseudo code that I have written.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   for (j = n; j >= 1; j--)
      cout << "hi";
```

From this piece of code, it's obvious that the time complexity for the upper bound of the outer for loop is O(n).

However, what would the time complexity for the inner for loop be?

Comment: `O(n)`, since you start from `j` equal `n` and stop at `j` equal `0`. The outer loop is in `O(n^2)`, because it repeats `n` times a loop in `O(n)`.

Comment: The complexity of `cout<<"hi"` when repeated is unspecified, and can vary between implementations (e.g. sensitivity to strategies for buffering and flushing of the buffers).

Answer (score 1):

The statement in the inner loop gets executed `n*n` times what results in the complexity of `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)//                 O(n)
   for (j = n; j >= 1; j--)//              O(n)
      cout << "hi";//                      O(1)
```

Total: `O(n)*O(n)*O(1)=O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

`for (j = n; j >= 1; j--)` and `for(j = 0; j <= n; j++)` are equivalent statements as far as how many times they will be executed, one just counts from the upper bound to 0 and the other counts from zero to the upper bound